# How to close navigation before scrolling to an anchor point?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm creating my first one-page project, so I want to be able to scroll around easily.

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#top">Top</a></li>
    <li><a href="#middle">Middle</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bottom">Bottom</a></li>
  </ul>
  <span id="hamburger">Hamburger Icon</span>
</nav>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#hamburger").on("click", function() {
  $("nav ul li").toggleSlide("normal");
});

//Snipet code from CSS-Tricks

$(function() {        
        $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
            //Added code
            if($('nav ul').is(':visible')) {
                $('nav').slideToggle("fast");
            }
            //End added code
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 700);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

I'm stuck at mobile-first template. Basically, when I click on the Hamburger Icon, the menu appears as "blocks". When I choose an anchor point, it should close the menu and scroll to the anchor. Things seem simple, yet it doesn't work well as I thought. When I click the anchor point, the menu disappears and scrolls to my destined point very well. However, now the menu can't be opened again, no matter how I click on the "Hamburger icon".

Btw, I'm just start using JQuery, so I hope to see a clear instruction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use slideToggle for both of your animations.  I would also just animate the `nav ul`  Instead of the `nav ul li` that way your are just animating one item instead of multiple items for no reason.  So in your css change the `nav ul`  to `display:none`  instead of the `nav ul li`.  Also there is probably no reason to check if `nav ul`  is visible because no matter what you are going to be scrolling to a section if a link in your menu is clicked.  So that being said you could just use the following code:

Here is a working Fiddle [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/Laf6rp4L/)

```
$("#hamburger").on("click", function() {
  $("nav ul").slideToggle("normal");
});

//Snipet code from CSS-Tricks

$(function() {        
        $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {

            //Added code
             $('nav ul').slideToggle("fast");

            //End added code
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 700);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```